# How to get specific part in array from ical file with php

Tags: php

I have file, i need all part with start `BEGIN:VEVENT` and end `END:VEVENT`, I need all that string which contains all this part need in array, i have below string

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
LOCATION:Test Location
DESCRIPTION:Test Description
DTSTART:20190507T185657Z
DTEND:20190507T185657Z
SUMMARY:Test Summary
URL:http://xxxxxxxxx
DTSTAMP:20190507T185657Z
UID:5cdaa1cd6c3c3
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
LOCATION:Test Location
DESCRIPTION:Test Description
DTSTART:20190508T185657Z
DTEND:20190508T185657Z
SUMMARY:Test Summary
URL:http://xxxxxxxxx
DTSTAMP:20190508T185657Z
UID:5cdaa1cd6c3cc
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I need this 2 part in array

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
LOCATION:Test Location
DESCRIPTION:Test Description
DTSTART:20190507T185657Z
DTEND:20190507T185657Z
SUMMARY:Test Summary
URL:http://xxxxxxxxx
DTSTAMP:20190507T185657Z
UID:5cdaa1cd6c3c3
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT

LOCATION:Test Location
DESCRIPTION:Test Description
DTSTART:20190508T185657Z
DTEND:20190508T185657Z
SUMMARY:Test Summary
URL:http://xxxxxxx
DTSTAMP:20190508T185657Z
UID:5cdaa1cd6c3cc
END:VEVENT
```

Can anyone please help me how can we get that ?

Comment: Nikul please consider reading this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and showing what you have tried before just asking other people to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture everything `.*` non-greedy `?` in between your begin and end delimiters with the `s` modifier (`.` matches all characters, including newlines):

```
$text = file_get_contents('/path/to/file.txt');
preg_match_all('/BEGIN:VEVENT.*?END:VEVENT/s', $text, $result);
print_r($result[0]);
```